# 'SchoolContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working with ASP.NET core 2.0 console application

I am on entity framework core 2.0 and I am having error

**'SchoolContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder)': no suitable method found to override**

And

**I can't find my project.json file**

there's lot of solution to work out with project.json file

but i don't see it anywhere

[image: ERROR MSG]

I am stuck for 3 hours now

there's a link I have been following

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it seems that you have created a local `DbContextOptionsBuilder` class instead of using from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder. Can you please confirm what `DbContextOptionsBuilder`  file contains? If has the class then delete it.

Comment: There is no method `OnConfiguring` to override

Comment: thanks , now i am facing, **add-migration is not recognized problem**

Comment: and i can't find the **.json** file to work with the solutions over the internet

Comment: If you don't ahave appSetttings.json to define the settings then add the one

Comment: project.json is from the ASP.NET Core 1.0 preview era on Visual Studio 2015, it was deprecated even before the 1.0 release. Whatever you are reading, it is very outdated

Comment: then how i can i solve it, i am in real dark

Answer (score 1):

To override `OnModelCreating` and `OnConfiguring` methods, you need to have installed a *NuGet* package called *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*.

You can do it when you right click on `Solution -> NuGet Packages -> Install -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`.